# Raster R extract function for large datasets

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, extract, raster

I am trying to calculate summary statistics (in this case mean) for 1 m2 grid (polygon) over 3 ha. My input raster dataset is gathered from UAV with a spatial resolution of 0.05 m. In total, I have 20 stacked bands covering 3 ha that I want to extract mean values for 1 m grid. First I stacked all rasters (which was fast) and then use raster:: extract function together with 1 m2 grid size shapefile to summarise the information using below code

`VI_extract_mean <- raster::extract(final_stacked, data, fun=mean, df=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)`

Here; 
final_stacked: stacked raster files 
data: 1 m2 grid shape file

I have a 64 GB RAM computer. The analysis is running for more than 8 hrs but no results. The issue is I have large number of similar datasets. Any tips to speed up the process.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use clusterR() and take advantage of multiple cores on your machine or in your environment. Martin Šiklar has a nice blog post that addresses exactly what you need: https://www.gis-blog.com/increasing-the-speed-of-raster-processing-with-r-part-33-cluster/